# Tiles render a black margin depending of screen size

Tags: graphics

I have a rendering problem since long time and I don't know how to solve it. I develop roguelike game where I display a 2D TopView map based on a simple png file like this :

[image: test.png]

But, with different game lib, I have the same problem (it seems to be not on all computer) when a resize the windows. A black border is sometime visible (depending on windows size).

[image: resize bug]

I think it is “float” related. Tiles position, size, etc. are floats. Maybe float usage by gpu make pixel selection “error” on source texture ? I don't know. Any idea about what happens ? And how to solve ?

If you want to try it, the code is in Rust.

*Use mini tileset as test.png*

File **Cargo.toml** :

```
[package]
name = "demo_squads"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
macroquad = "0.3"
```

File **src/main.rs** :

```
use macroquad::prelude::*;

#[macroquad::main("test")]
async fn main() {
    let tile_size = 32.;
    let world_size_tiles = 64; // square world
    let world_size = world_size_tiles as f32 * tile_size;
    let texture = load_texture("test.png").await.unwrap();
    let background_tile_source = Rect::new(0., 0., tile_size, tile_size);
    let foreground_tile_source = Rect::new(32., 32., tile_size, tile_size);

    loop {
        clear_background(BLACK);

        let zoom_x = (world_size / screen_width()) * 2.;
        let zoom_y = (world_size / screen_height()) * 2.;

        set_camera(&Camera2D {
            zoom: Vec2::new(zoom_x, zoom_y),
            offset: Vec2::new(-0.5, 0.),
            ..Default::default()
        });

        for row_i in 0..world_size_tiles {
            for col_i in 0..world_size_tiles {
                let real_dest_x = col_i as f32 * tile_size;
                let real_dest_y = row_i as f32 * tile_size;
                let camera_dest_x = real_dest_x / world_size;
                let camera_dest_y = real_dest_y / world_size;
                let dest_size_x = tile_size / world_size;
                let dest_size_y = tile_size / world_size;

                // background
                draw_texture_ex(
                    texture,
                    camera_dest_x,
                    camera_dest_y,
                    WHITE,
                    DrawTextureParams {
                        source: Some(background_tile_source),
                        dest_size: Some(Vec2::new(dest_size_x, dest_size_y)),
                        flip_y: true,
                        ..Default::default()
                    },
                );

                // foreground
                draw_texture_ex(
                    texture,
                    camera_dest_x,
                    camera_dest_y,
                    WHITE,
                    DrawTextureParams {
                        source: Some(foreground_tile_source),
                        dest_size: Some(Vec2::new(dest_size_x, dest_size_y)),
                        flip_y: true,
                        ..Default::default()
                    },
                );
            }
        }

        next_frame().await
    }
}
```

What happening here ? And idea to prevent this ?

Comment: This (and the image blurriness) is caused by sprites not being aligned to the pixel grid.

Comment: Hello @HolyBlackCat , It it a common problem in tile painting ? So, "problematics" values are camera_dest_x and camera_dest_y ?

Comment: Yes, probably those. Round them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't round them : The camera system of this lib need relative positions. I have to find another relative mechanism to be able to round them.

Comment: I don't understand. Just round them before passing them to `draw_texture_ex`, it shouldn't affect anything else?

Comment: With this code, camera_dest_x and camera_dest_y and valued between 0.0 and 1.0 when given to draw_texture_ex. If rounded, they egual 0 or 1.

Comment: Multiply by window size, round, then divide back.

Comment: It was a good idea, but the black border is larger than before :(